Excel recognizes the "date time" format in the chart but not in the x-axis calculation
I have imported data from my thermostat. The first two columns are "date" and "time" in the d/m/yy and hh:mm:ss formats respectively.
Excel is brilliant and recognized that those two columns together were to be used as x-axis, and they appear combined when I probe a data point on chart.
But somehow it cannot display the right date along the x-axis. Date starts at 1/0/00 0:00 and increments way too fast. It looks like it's not using the right formula.
FYI: Microsoft® Excel for Mac, Version 16.88 (24081116)


I tried to change the Format axis>Number>Category and >Type to all available including custom Format Code but that only affects the display, not the computed date.

It's not really a StackOverflow question as it's not about programming.  Assuming I understand you correctly - click on the chart, go to Chart Design, Select Data. click on Edit in the Horizontal Axis Labels and select both columns as the Axis label range.

The images illustrate what you described. As you can see the probed point displays the data from the two columns. Excel is not parsing it the right way along the x-axis.

My understanding is that "8/22/24" is an integer (=45526) and "06:00:00" a fraction (=0.25) in units of days that excel would parse into a date. Correct?

No, Excel wouldn't do it itself.

In your case, Excel displays x-axis marks as is. To allow Excel to accept timestamp data correctly, you need to combine them altogether:
=INT([@Date])+[@Time]-INT([@Time])

In the formula above we cut the possible (not displayed) fractional part in the Date and then get the fractional part only from Time.
Typically, if date and time values are entered as they displayed above, Date points to midnight (integer value only), and INT(Time) is zero. But, for sure, we shouldn't expect data integrity for data get from the untrusted source.


I'm not sure why the INT. The time hh:mm:ss is a fractional value and that will always be 0.

As we can on the screenshot, Excel recognizes the timestamp correctly.
